# How to keep a thread alive forever until JVM is killed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread which i wanted to run always until the JVM is stopped. What is the best way to do that ?

```
public void run() {
    String event = sc.nextLine();
    try {
          queue.put(event); // thread will block here
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: With a loop.  Note:  Put your loop *inside* your `try` block, so that other code can interrupt it.  An interrupt is a request for a thread to stop whatever it's doing.

Comment: To keep it alive, don't return.  Then it won't die until your program exists, or the last non-daemon thread exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding an infinite loop should do the trick

```
public void run() {
   while(true){
        String event = sc.nextLine();
        try {
          queue.put(event); // thread will block here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that as this is written it will loop forever, not let itself be interrupted, and keep the JVM instance alive. You'll have to issue a kill command to remove the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) { runBody(); }
```

Add exception handling if necessary.